# mongodb full text search and json objects

Tags: mongodb, search, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I am running mongodb v2.4.5. I have a document with the following fields:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("<someid>"), temp:"python", github_repo_languages" : { "python" : 17, "java" : 984 } }
```

If I run the query:

```
db.users.runCommand( "text", { search: "java" })

{
"queryDebugString" : "java||||||",
"language" : "english",
"results" : [ ],
"stats" : {
    "nscanned" : 0,
    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
    "n" : 0,
    "nfound" : 0,
    "timeMicros" : 97
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

mongodb doesn't find any documents.

Here are my indexes:

```
> db.users.getIndexes()
[
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "workingon.users",
    "name" : "_id_"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_fts" : "text",
        "_ftsx" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "workingon.users",
    "name" : "users_text_index",
    "weights" : {
        "$**" : 1
    },
    "default_language" : "english",
    "language_override" : "language",
    "textIndexVersion" : 1
}
]
```

Other searches work for simple text fields.  Is the issue the complex json object?  Are there plans to add complex json objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/text-search/ ) the text index should be on the field or fields whose value is a string or an array of string elements. So as you pointed out, the json field will not work.

Comment: @drfence, to me, it is also a very important point to be mentioned clearly. I saw it just because I had a lot of interest on the question.

Comment: I submitted a change request to call it out more clearly, perhaps they'll accept it.

Comment: Downvoter, a comment in addition to a downvote is more helpful than just a downvote.